# Mongoose array returns empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add mongoose Id's to my 2 arrays, but it comes back as empty arrays.
I can't seem to find what's wrong here is my function,

```
exports.create = (body) => {
    console.log(body.projectName);
    const theDate = getDate();
    qpTemplate.findOne().sort({version: -1}).exec(function(err, doc) {
        var answerArray = [];
        var questionArray = [];
        var newProject = new projectModel({
        _id: id(),
        owner: Id,
        projectName: body.projectName,
        date: theDate,
        version: 1.0,
        });
        var qp = new questionPackageModel ({
          _id: id(),
          version: 1,
          questionIds: [], // this one i want to populate
          projectId: newProject._id
        });
        console.log("hej")
        doc.questionIds.map(theId => {
          questionTemplate.findById(theId, function (err, question) {
            var theQuestion = new questionModel({
                    _id: id(),
                    qpId: qp._id,
                    categoryId: question.categoryId,
                    order: question.order,
                    version: question.version,
                    question: question.question,
                    answerIds: [], // this one i want to populate
                    name: question.name,
                    legacyName: question.legacyName,
                    description: question.description
            })
                  question.answerIds.map(answerId => {
                    answerTemplate.findById(answerId, function (err, answer) {
                      var theAnswer = new answerModel({
                        _id: id(),
                        questionId: theQuestion._id,
                        name: answer.name,
                        order: answer.order,
                        answerText: answer.answerText,
                        value: answer.value,
                        placeholder: answer.placeholder,
                        settings:answer.settings,
                        description: answer.description
                      })
                      theQuestion.answerIds.push(theAnswer._id); // returns an empty array at the end
                      answerArray.push(theAnswer);
                      theAnswer.save();
                    });
                })

                qp.questionIds.push(theQuestion._id); // returns an empty array in the end
                questionArray.push(theQuestion);
                theQuestion.save()
           });
        })
        newProject.qpId = qp._id;
        qp.save();
        newProject.save();
        console.log(questionArray);
        console.log(newProject)
        return(items={answerArray,questionArray,qp,newProject})
      })

  }
```

What i'm trying to accomplish is to connect the models to eachother with their ids that's why I'm adding their id's to the array. I don't want the whole object in there since i'm then pushing this data to a redux client that require a flat state.

** I'm thankful for every answer! **

Comment: Hey, maybe this article about built-in _update many_ with Mongoose can help you: https://medium.com/@salonimalhotra1ind/update-multiple-documents-in-mongoose-ea37c04a154f

Comment: Where is your id function ? How you define it ?

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, but they don't cover arrays there :P

Comment: Hi i define it like this: 
var Id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is using a synchronous operation ([`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) with asynchronous lookups (`findById`) and then saving the document before the asynchronous operations have completed. You will need to use something like [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or some asynchronous library to ensure all asynchronous operations are completed before you attempt to save the document.

Currently the code flow is:

- Lookup template (async)

  - Create two documents (sync)
  - Map over template array (sync)
  - Lookup questions (async) *Everything nested below won't finish before save*
  - Create new document (sync)
  - Map over template array (sync)

    - Lookup answers (async) *Everything nested below won't finish before save*
    - Attempt to push to array (sync)
    - Attempt to push to array (sync)
  - Save documents (async)

Without a lot of refactoring for optimizations you *could* start with using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wrap all of the mapped lookups and return them:

```
// Pseudo untested code focusing on the promise aspect only
// `create` is now a Promise
exports create = (body) => {
  return qpTemplate.findOne().exec().then((template) => {
    // Create projectModel and questionPackageModel documents
    newProject.qpId = qp._id;

    return Promise.all(
      template.questionIds.map((theId) =>
        questionTemplate.findById(theId).exec().then((question) => {
          // Create questionModel document
          qp.questionIds.push(theQuestion._id);

          return Promise.all(
            question.answerIds.map((answerId) =>
              answerTemplate.findById(answerId).exec().then((answer) => {
                // Create answerModel document
                theQuestion.answerIds.push(answer._id);
                return theAnswer.save();
            )
          ).then(() => theQuestion.save());
        }
      ).then(
        () => Promise.all([qp.save(), newProject.save()])
      ).then(
        () => {answerArray,questionArray,qp,newProject}
      )
    );
 }
```

Comment: How would you write it?

Comment: I don't get it, i've been looking up aync / await, but I don't seem to get it to work, should I do .then() ?

Comment: @Charlie I've included some pseudo code to guide you but if you aren't familiar with promises (for which async/await is a nice sugar syntax for them) then I would begin with researching how promises work.

Comment: Thank you :) i tried your code and i get this error , Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel.
I guess i have to research some more about promises. It's just that I only have this function that needs it in my whole project..